# Why doesn't the JavaScript minifier use the variable it's assigned to 'this'

Tags: javascript, minify

When I minify my code, I notice that the minifier will do something like (formatted for readability):

```
e.prototype.doSomething = function(){
  var s=this;
  this.anotherThing();
  ........ //more code
}
```

Why doesn't it use `s.anotherThing()` and keeps using `this`. It seems it only uses `s` when referencing `this` from the inner scope of a function or callback in my doSomething() function.

Comment: What is your original code here? Does it have something like `var self = this; this.anotherThing();` in it?

Comment: "Why doesn't it use s.anotherThing() and keeps using this." It could use both here. However, functions define their own local `this` variable, so they need `s` to refer to the outer function `this`.

Comment: @VLAZ even if I had something like `var self = this`, wouldn't it be smaller (more minified) to use `s` instead of `this`? In a large file thats a few extra kb's could be saved!

Comment: @garethb 1. the minifier might not want to re-write your code like that. Yes, it's safe (here\*) but it's probably not worth it. 2. \* it's safe *here*, not necessarily generically. 3. you'd save 3 *bytes* 4. even then, `this` is likely to be more times in a file. If you're sending the file gzipped (which is pretty commonly set up by default) then *repeated tokens* can be compressed more efficiently. All in all, you might get few bytes less. Or maybe not. A minifier might choose not to re-write that and it's going to be a big deal.